# mod_rewrite with trailing period in URL

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have a RewriteRule on my Apache to make URLs friendly

```
RewriteRule ^log/(.+)$ script.php?u=$1 [QSA]
```

This makes http://example.com/log/username get internally redirected to http://example.com/script.php?u=username

This works fine, as long as the username does not contain a trailing period. However, there are usernames, where people chose names like "firstname-L." (note the trailing period)

In this case http://example.com/firstname-L. gets translated to http://example.com/script.php?u=firstname-L (the trailing period is gone)

How can I get this to work?

Comment: what do you mean check your question's spelling.

Comment: Could you try a rule with an explicit trailing dot like `^log/(.+)\.$`? It may be the Apache web server that removes the trailing dot.

Comment: No, it's not Apache, if I enter the  http://example.com/script.php?u=firstname-L. it works correctly. If I print the $_GET on the redirected page, the trailing period is missing, when I do so on the http://example.com/script.php?u=firstname-L. it is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to check these configuration directives:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/log/(.+)\.$
RewriteRule ^log/(.+)$ /script.php?u=$1 [QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/log/(.+)\.$
RewriteRule ^log/(.+)$ /script.php?u=$1. [QSA]
```

OR:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/log/(.+)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1})$
RewriteRule ^log/(.+)$ /script.php?u=$1 [QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/log/(.+)\.$
RewriteRule ^log/(.+)$ /script.php?u=$1. [QSA]
```

I hope, I'm not mistaken.. Now, as the variable of usernames with one character or one character with trailing period won't work in the second code, we can try to replace the second code with this one:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/log/(.*)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1})$
RewriteRule ^log/(.+)$ /script.php?u=$1 [QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/log/(.*)\.$
RewriteRule ^log/(.*)$ /script.php?u=$1. [QSA]
```

Or you could try these three liner directives if you doesn't like the four liner:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/log/(.*)\.$
RewriteRule ^log/(.*)$ /script.php?u=$1. [QSA]
RewriteRule ^log/(.*)([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1})$ /script.php?u=$1$2 [QSA]
```

I hope, all these codes above will work!

Comment: That one does work, thanks for that. However, it's still a workaround and I will need to replace every rule (1 line) with four.

Comment: nope, tried that one before asking already, period is missing

Comment: @RainerMohr Please check the update again.. And don't forget to mention me which one of the first two sets are working? Do they both work?

Comment: Nope, won't work either. The first of the two lines ^log/(.+)\.$ never match for some reason. The first of your sets worked for me. So it looks like this will need the RewriteCond, as this matches, while the RewriteRule does not standalone

Comment: @RainerMohr Have you ever try the second code on the answer? I just want to know if it's working. And I also think, the last *"."* *(dot)* in the dynamic filename that you want to be redirecting on a `RewriteRule` doesn't match in `mod_rewrite`.

Comment: Yes, the second code works fine too. I also found a page, that says this is a windows only problem, on Linux this seems to work... But I can't verify

Comment: Problem with the second code though: Usernames with one character or one character with trailing period won't work...

Comment: @RainerMohr I think, this is my last update. Could you please check it!

Comment: Thanks Servant, Yes, the threeliner works :-) Thanks for your help. Marked as accepted

Answer (score 0):

Your rule appears to be right, perhaps the client or server is stripping the last dot as spurious (checked on YT with Chrome, if you add a dot at the end of a video url (`?=xxxxxxxxx` to `?=xxxxxxxxx.`) and press enter, it gets removed -- actually triggering a 303 HTTP response).

In general, you should use only upper/lowercase letters and non-trailing dashes or dots in urls to compose the so-called slug, which is guaranteed to be handled correctly across all decent browsers and web servers.