# Trailing zero lost from redirected URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

When attempting to get a variable from a URL if it ends in a dot (".") I am unable to get the dot. Often a dot is used in the end of the variable and is needed in order to search for the entry.

example -> a url of : "http://localhost/test/test/testing.testing./" will give me the following : $module="test", $var1="test", $var2="testing.testing"

```
//from url : http://localhost/test/test/testing.testing./
var_dump($_GET);  
// outputs array(3) { ["module"]=> string(4) "test" ["var1"]=> string(4) "test" ["var2"]=> string(15) "testing.testing" }
```

When using the URL : "http://localhost/?module=test&var1=test&var2=testing.testing." the output will be correct, including the trailing dot.

```
//from URL : http://localhost/?module=test&var1=test&var2=testing.testing.
var_dump($_GET);  
// outputs array(3) { ["module"]=> string(4) "test" ["var1"]=> string(4) "test" ["var2"]=> string(16) "testing.testing." }
```

I obviously would like to keep the cleaner URL structure, and not have to bypass it when the variable I am trying to pass contains a dot.

I have reason to believe it is an issue with my .htaccess, due to the fact that when the script is accessed in the url, it is able to receive the trailing dot.

My .htaccess looks like this :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ index.php?module=$1&var1=$2&var2=$3 [L]
```

I was also informed by a friend that this may be a windows problem, and if that is true, I was just curious if there is a work around. I am aware that I can probably get the variable by parsing through $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], however I would prefer to fix the other in the .htaccess over fudging it with PHP.

If any more information is needed let me know.
Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383339/mod-rewrite-with-trailing-period-in-url ?

Comment: That looks very promising. Ill try messing with that.

Comment: Yep, that got me in the right direction.
Too bad there is not some simple way to just allow periods in the URI

Answer (score 0):

how about ...

```
$path = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$params = explode("/", $path);
var_dump($params);
```

Comment: Yeah as I said in the end of my question : I can get it easily through $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], etc... however I would prefer to fix the the .htaccess to give the correct URL rather than correct it in PHP